# Псевдо-заголовки - как использовать?

Tags: c#, httpclient

Как использовать псевдо-заголовки в запросе ?

Получаю исключение System.FormatException: "The header name format is invalid."

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, "https://***.php");

    request.Headers.Add(":authority", "***.ru");
    request.Headers.Add(":method", "POST");
    request.Headers.Add(":path", "/***.php");
    request.Headers.Add(":scheme", "https");
```

В DevTools Chrome выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется вот так точно никак, а какую задачу вы решаете? Зачем вам эти заголовки?

Comment: @aepot хочу выполнить Post запрос, вроде все заголовки верно повторяю кроме этих, а ответ не тот что нужно получаю =) - Вот думаю этих не хватает. Да и сам факт, браузер их так отправляет, вот хочу повторить - типа я браузер, а как хз... гугление ":authority" не помогло

Comment: Хотя, блин - выполнил успешно post запрос без этих заголовков.
Но вот допустим хочу на 100% браузеру подражать, а он такие отправляет. Вот как мне повторить ?

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что в HTTP/1.1 эти заголовки считаются синтаксически неверными и используются для упаковки HTTP запроса в HTTP/2 протоколе? Вы же видите, что эти заголовки содержат? Это по сути протокол, url и метод запроса. Вот и вставляйте их содержимое в адрес и метод запроса.

Comment: @aepot нет - не в курсе(, я вместо того чтобы учиться постепенно, пытаюсь решить задачи здесь и сейчас xD - В итоге почти ничего не знаю, но иногда получается xD

Comment: Другими словами, оставьте работу с псевдозаголовками HTTP клиенту, они имеют служебное назначение. А если вы используете HTTP/1.1, то они и вовсе там не поддерживаются и существовать не могут.

Comment: @aepot А если хочу подражать браузеру в данный момент, значит я как то должен использовать HTTP/2 и там прописывать всё равно через request.Headers.Add ?

Comment: [RFC 7540 - 8.1.2.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-8.1.2) - долго объяснять, как это работает. Так что лучше почитайте первоисточник.

Comment: @aepot оО источник - здорово! Спасибо!

Comment: Очень кратко - вам не нужно использовать псевдо-заголовки в запросах. Только `HttpClientHandler` знает, когда нужно и когда можно, и сам их использует. Вы можете включить поддержку HTTP/2 в свойствах при создании `HttpClientHandler`, если используете .NET Core 3.1 или более новый .NET. Псевдо-заголовки не являются HTTP заголовками и не имеют с ними ничего общего, они работают иначе.

Comment: @aepot значит я уже использую) httpClient.DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0); Учусь на вашем примере 7ми месячной давности xD

Comment: @aepot А это нормально что в HttpAnalyzer ( софт анализа запросов) при использовании  httpClient.DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0); Вот такие данные показывает в Header POST /***.php HTTP/1.1